# Add shared lib.so to android project

Tags: android, shared-libraries, android-ndk

I have an Android project using some native functions. Native functions are using some functions from external shared library "external_lib.so"
I've added to Android.mk: "-lexternal_lib -L/path/to/external/lib" line and myjni.so have been linked successfully. But during runtime  myjni.so loading error occurred. The size of myjni.so reflects that external_lib.so is not included. How to fix the problem?

LOCAL_PATH := $(call my-dir)

include $(CLEAR_VARS)

LOCAL_MODULE    := myjni
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := myjni.c
LOCAL_LDLIBS :=  -ldl -llog -lz **-lexternal_lib -L/path/to/external/lib**

include $(BUILD_SHARED_LIBRARY)

Comment: Hi Michael, I have same issue. Did you solve the issue ? Please share me your solution. I have stacked in there and can't resolve issue. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

is the .so a third party prebuilt shared library?
if so, in your Android.mk, you need to have:

...

LOCAL_SHARED_LIBRARY := curl

...

LOCAL_LDLIBS += -L$(ANDROID_LIBCURL_LIB_PATH) -lcurl
LOCAL_SHARED_LIBRARIES := curl

include $(BUILD_SHARED_LIBRARY)